# CK Editor Not Working Well on Safari Browser

Tags: javascript, safari, ckeditor

I am using CKeditor form for editing my web page content.
The CKeditor textarea is working fine on the browsers Chrome, Mozilla and Opera
but my client is working on Safari.

The version of CKeditor I am using is version 4.5.7

I tested with 4.4.1 & 4.5.5 but this gave the same result.
Is there solution available on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can get more help here [Check this](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/issues/491)

And get patch for 4.4.5 [here](https://github.com/mattbrictson/ckeditor/tree/ckeditor-4.4.5-quick-patch)